# Lollipop sequence numbering

Tags: c

I am using an embedded wireless system where it generates data packets at a defined time interval. The aim is to detect when the device/system is rebooted. For this, I read that Lollipop sequence numbering is a numbering scheme best fitted for this.

"In this numbering scheme, sequence numbers start at a negative value, increase until they reach zero, then cycle through a finite set of positive numbers indefinitely. When a system is rebooted, the sequence is restarted from a negative number again. This allows recently rebooted systems to be distinguished from systems which have simply looped around their numbering space.""

Although, I know the theory of how it works, have not been able to implement in C for my platform.

My algorithm is very simple and works as such:

```
int sequence_num = 0;

generate_data_packet();

sequence_num++;
```

This sequence_num has to be lollipop sequence numbering pattern.

Can anyone provide some code snippets as to how this might look like in C?

Comment: Like this: `if(++seqnum > maxnum) { seqnum = 0; }`

Comment: Also `int sequence_num = <some negative value, not 0>`.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You're not starting from a negative number and you're not cycling, where's your lollipop?

As @WeatherVane and @0x5453 suggest, do something like:

```
const int start_value = -10;  // where you begin
const int max_value = 10; // where you loop

int sequence_num = start_value;

generate_data_packet();

++sequence_num;
if (sequence_num > max_value) {
    sequence_num = 0;
}
```

Comment: I agree and that's what I wanted to know as to how to go about it. You have clarified my doubts.  Thanks...